# Laravel - Aggregate Sum only Works Per Page

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

In my Controller I have this code:

```php
public function salesReport(Request $request)
    {

        $billings = DB::table('sales')
            ->select(
                'cust_code',
                'trans_id',
                DB::raw('created_at as created_date'), 'amount',)->orderByRaw('created_at DESC');

        if (isset($request->start_date) && isset($request->end_date)) {
            $billings = $billings->whereBetween('created_at', [$start_date . ' 00:00:00', $end_date . ' 23:59:59']);
            $render['start_date'] = $request->start_date;
            $render['end_date'] = $request->end_date;
        } elseif (isset($request->start_date)) {
            $billings = $billings->where('created_at', $request->start_date);
            $render['start_date'] = $request->start_date;
        }
        $billings = $billings->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
        $billings = $billings->paginate(15);
        $billings = $billings->appends($render);
        $data['billings'] = $billings;
        return view('report.bbnaijaonetimebillingsReport', $data);
    }
```

I want to perform aggregate sum for amount based on the selected item.

I did this in the view:

```
<td>{{ $billing->cust_code }}</td>
<td>{{ $billing->trans_id }}</td>
<td>{{ $billing->created_date }}</td>
<td>{{ $billing->amount }}</td>
```

Then I use this to perform the aggregate sum:

> {{ $billings->sum('amount') }}

But what I observed is that, it performs the sum function per pagination (page displayed). But I don't want that. I want sum per selected items, even if there are 5 pages, it should sum all.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I am using Laravel Version 5.8

Comment: You have a syntax problem in `DB::raw('created_at as created_date'), 'amount',)`, problem: 
`,` after amount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you paginate $billings, therefore you get sum of paginated objects.
Make another object like `$sumBillings` and put in another query

```
    public function salesReport(Request $request)
    {

        $sumBillings = DB::table('sales')
        ->select(
           'cust_code', 
           'trans_id',
             DB::raw('created_at as created_date'),
           'amount',
      )               
     ->orderByRaw('created_at DESC')
        if(isset($request->start_date) && isset($request->end_date))
        {
            $sumBillings=$sumBillings->whereBetween('created_at',[$start_date.' 00:00:00',$end_date.' 23:59:59']);
            $render['start_date']=$request->start_date;
            $render['end_date']=$request->end_date;
        }elseif(isset($request->start_date))
        {
            $sumBillings=$sumBillings->where('created_at',$request->start_date);
            $render['start_date']=$request->start_date;
        }         
        $sumBillings= $sumBillings->orderBy('created_at','DESC');
        $sumBillings->get();
        $sumBillings= $sumBillings->appends($render);

$billings = DB::table('sales')
    ->select(
       'cust_code', 
       'trans_id',
         DB::raw('created_at as created_date'),
       'amount',
  )               
 ->orderByRaw('created_at DESC')
    if(isset($request->start_date) && isset($request->end_date))
    {
        $billings=$billings->whereBetween('created_at',[$start_date.' 00:00:00',$end_date.' 23:59:59']);
        $render['start_date']=$request->start_date;
        $render['end_date']=$request->end_date;
    }elseif(isset($request->start_date))
    {
        $billings=$billings->where('created_at',$request->start_date);
        $render['start_date']=$request->start_date;
    }         
    $billings= $billings->orderBy('created_at','DESC');
    $billings= $billings->paginate(15);
    $billings= $billings->appends($render);
    $data['billings'] = $billings; 

return view('report.bbnaijaonetimebillingsReport',$data)->with('sumBillings', $sumBillings);
```

Comment: or event it should be possible to make it between like that: 
` $billings= $billings->orderBy('created_at','DESC');
$sum = $billings->sum('amount');
    $billings= $billings->paginate(15);`
and then 
`{{$sum}}`

Comment: Please how do I merge the query  $sumBillings you wrote to what I have in my original code

Comment: `public function salesReport(Request $request)
{
$sumBillings = DB::table('sales')
    ->select(
       'cust_code', 
       'trans_id',
         DB::raw('created_at as created_date'),
       'amount',
  )->get();`

and then the rest

Comment: ow, and at the end 
`return view('report.bbnaijaonetimebillingsReport',$data)->with('sumBillings', $sumBillings)';`

Comment: It sum up now. But when I filter based on date it total doesnt change

Comment: Am sorry. Its like you dont understand me. You know that in my current code I have $billings   that performs the query and filter. Now am adding $sumBillings, which I have done. The two queries are in the same controller, but I need to also perform my aggregate sum based on filter in the initial query I have.  I observed that you removed pagination and $data. I will still need the two

Comment: yes, just add it to your $billings, add this to your code, and then create $billings as well

Comment: When I added the code, I have this error:      Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::appends()